# set -e is shadowing signal function

Tags: bash

I am running bash 4.4.19 on MacOS. I found the signal function doesn't work when if "set -e" is set. is it expected behavior?  Here is my sample code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
set -e
declare -A Array1
Array1=([index1]="abc" [index2]="def" [index3]="dfkdjkfjdkdjfdk")
trap ReactSignal USR1

fun() {
    PPid=$1
    NUM=0
    Array1[index4]="insidefunction"
    while [ $NUM -le 5 ]
    do
    ((NUM++))
 echo "inside number is $NUM"
 sleep 1 
done
    kill -USR1 $PPid
}

ReactSignal() {
    IFS= read -r -d '' -u 3 checkOutput
    echo "function output is ${checkOutput}"
}

Ppid="$$"
echo "start...."
coproc funfd { fun $Ppid; }
exec 3>&${funfd[0]}
echo "end...."
sleep 7
echo  array value is ${Array1[@]}
```

Comment: Because when you `set -e`, the `((NUM++))` command fails at the first iteration so it never gets to the `kill` command which sends the signal. When I say "fails" I mean it returns exit code 1. so `(( 0 ))` returns 1 and `(( 1 ))` returns 0. The irony :) What you can do is to combine the while condition with the increment, like `while (( NUM++ <= 5 )); do ... `

Comment: Yet another reason to avoid `set -e` :). Personally, I'd go for a `for` loop: `for (( NUM = 1; NUM <= 5; ++NUM)); do ... done`. That best expresses intent, IMHO. If you want to evaluate numeric expressions while `set -e` is enabled (not that I recommend enabling it), you can use `: $((...))`, which doesn't actually check the value. Of course, you could also `declare -i NUM=0` and then `NUM+=1`. That has the useful side effect of making `NUM` local to the function in which the `declare` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `((expression))` actually has a *return code,* as per the `bash` documentation:

> `((expression))`
>
> The  expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION`.  If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.

So, of course, if `NUM` is zero going in to the expression, the return code will be one and `set -e` will pick this up as an error that needs termination.

---

There are any number of ways to solve this, from using the (rather ugly, in my opinion):

```
set +e ; ((NUM++)); set -e
```

to not using `((expression))` at all:

```
for i in {0..4} ; do
    doSomethingWith $i
done
```